# Pandas melt columns associated to an attribute per year into seperate columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this. I am trying to combine columns associated with an attribute per year into separate columns. X, Y, and Z are the attributes.

```
|country|X_score_2018|X_score_2019|Y_score_2018|Y_score_2019|Z_score_2018|Z_score_2019|
|usa    |1           |9           |6           |2           |5           |7           |
|italy  |5           |2           |4           |1           |3           |8           |
|spain  |3           |2           |1           |8           |5           |4           |
```

My expected output is like this:-

```
|country|X_score|Y_score|Z_score|
|usa    |1      |6      |5
|italy  |5      |4      |3
|spain  |3      |1      |5
|usa    |9      |2      |7
|italy  |2      |1      |8
|spain  |2      |8      |4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a reason you don't want a column for year? As is, this would be a one-way transformation.

Comment: Yes, I donot want column for the year. I just want to stack the columns for X,Y and Z . I tried df.melt(id_vars='country',  value_name='X_score'). But I have to subset the data first and I do not want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try pandas [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) :

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames=["X_score", "Y_score", "Z_score"],
                i="country",
                j="year", 
                sep="_")
.droplevel(-1))


         X_score    Y_score Z_score
country         
usa        1           6    5
italy      5           4    3
spain      3           1    5
usa        9           2    7
italy      2           1    8
spain      2           8    4
```